# How to Initialize 2d ArrayList with 0 in one line

Tags: java, arraylist

How to Initialize all the element of 2d Array List in Java with 0 in single line of code without using for lop.

ArrayList of m rows and n columns.

How to initialise  value of all the elements to 0 at the time of defining it.

Comment: There's no 2D ArrayList in java. You can have `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`, that comes close to 2D. But also, what do you mean by `How to initialise its value to 0`? You mean the first element in the ArrayList? Or do you want `ArrayList<ArrayList > x = null;`?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you meant by 2D ArrayList, but you returned type of `List` instead of `ArrayList` with help of below:

```
List<List<Integer>> a=Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(0));
```

For normal `arrays` you can do something :

```
int[][] b=new int[1][2];
```